# Отключение подсветки кнопки

Tags: linux, клавиатура, archlinux

Как контролировать подсветку **одной** кнопки на клавиатуре? У меня есть общее освещение для клавиатуры, которое я могу контролировать, а также на некоторых кнопках есть дополнительные диоды, означающие "кнопка нажата". Можно ли как-то контролировать эти диоды? Надо, чтобы даже если кнопка нажата, диод не горел. Может есть какой-то файл, который это контролит и туда можно `0` прописать скриптом?

**upd:**

нашёл в `/sys/class/leds/` линки с кнопками, для которых есть подсветка, может нужно там что-то изменять?

**upd2:**

по линкам перешёл к драйверу нужной кнопки, там есть файл `brightness`, содержащий `255`, когда кнопка горит и `0`, когда нет. Попробовал `sudo echo '0' | sudo tee --append brightness`, когда кнопка горит - кнопка гореть перестала, но всё ещё считается нажатой!

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что нашёл решение.

1) Найдите драйвер для индикатора необходимой кнопки в `/sys/class/leds/`

2) В папке драйвера можно контролировать яркость диода кнопки, устанавливая значение файла `brightness` от 0 до 255 (если кнопка либо горит, либо нет, то возможные значения - 0 и 255)

3) Думаю, если изменить значение файла `max_brightness` с 1 на 0, то кнопка вообще никогда гореть не будет, но я это не проверял, т.к. в моем случае достаточно в скрипте, который задействует эту кнопку, прописать следующее, чтобы кнопка работала, но не горела.

```
sudo echo '0' | sudo tee --append /sys/devices/путь к драйверу/brightness > dev/null
```

Comment: А зачем эта магия с конвейером и `tee`?